# Table containing images white borders (Chrome)

Tags: html, image, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

Edit: It works fine in Firefox; it seems to happen only on chrome.

I am writing an application which requires me to cut an image into pieces and store those in a table. To do so I use the following (this is generated) html

```css
.no-padding {padding: 0!important;}
```

```html
<table class="table" id="game_puzzle">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/0_0.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/0_1.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/0_2.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/0_3.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/0_4.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/1_0.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/1_1.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/1_2.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/1_3.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/1_4.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/2_0.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/2_1.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/2_2.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/2_3.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/2_4.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/3_0.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/3_1.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/3_2.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/3_3.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/3_4.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/4_0.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/4_1.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/4_2.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/4_3.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
            <td class="no-padding"><img src="assets/images/kings of leon/5/4_4.png" style="width:100%">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The above code looks fine on most screen sizes, for example:

[image: Working]

But on other screen sizes(not only smaller ones) it looks like this:

[image: Not working]

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

are you using bootstrap framework? If not remove border's for table manually as shown below.

```
table, tr, th, td {
    border: 0;
}
```

Still you are facing the issue. Please update your code snippet.

Comment: I am using bootstrap and this didn't fix it.